# Converting string in a Pandas data frame to float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I have the following data frame:

```
Bestand = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['NaN', 'IE00B4X9L533', 'IE00BF4RFH31'],
                'Marktwert': ['217.803,37', '47.755,10', '15.353,32']})
```

In order to calculate with the second column named "Marktwert", I have to convert the string as a float, the sting has German format, that means the decimal point is a comma and the thousands separator is a dot. The number 217.803,37 has the datatype object.

If I try to convert using the code

```
Bestand['Marktwert'] = pd.to_numeric(Bestand['Marktwert'], downcast="float")
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "217.803,37" at position 0
```

Can anyone help me out pls?

Comment: `Bestand.Marktwert.str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',','.').astype(float)`

Comment: ISIN and Marktwert are no in the same length. try to make length to the same

Comment: @Cyttorak Ty works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're reading the data from a file, many of Pandas' file readers like `pandas.read_csv()` have `decimal` and `thousands` arguments for exactly this case.

Comment: Ty,  indeed I use read_csv(), but I am not familia with it, what arugments could I use here?
This the code I use currently:
Bestand = 'Verm�gensaufstellung.csv'
Bestand = pd.read_csv(Bestand, sep=';')

Comment: As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html): `Bestand = pd.read_csv(Bestand, sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')`

Comment: Ty, will it also handle the thousands separtor, which is in german format a dot?

Comment: Great ty, perfect!